# Are there hotkeys to cycle left and right through the list of candidates in the Windows 7 Pinyin Chinese IME?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, input, chinese, ime

I'm using the standard Simplified Chinese Pinyin IME (Input Method Editor) on Windows 7.1

You type in Pinyin (standard Romanization of Chinese) and a small window shows you a selection of candidate words in Hanzi (characters), about seven or so:
[image: example image of using the Windows 7.1 Simplified Chinese Pinyin IME]

You choose by clicking on a candidate with the mouse or by typing the number next to it.

You can scroll left and right through the candidates by clicking the left/right angle buttons at the right hand end.

Once a Chinese friend mentioned that you can also scroll left/right using some keys instead of having to reach for the mouse. But I didn't catch which keys they said and have been unable to find them by experimenting.

Which keys scroll left and right?

---

<sup>Please don't answer telling me to install some other IME. I just want to know what the keys are.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numbers to select a candidate, and pageup/pagedown to show the next batch of candidates.

You can find more info in the help that is displayed when clicking on the help button in the language bar (when it is separated from the taskbar).

Comment: Yes this is it! I thought I tried all the keys but since I have a netbook with a limited keyboard missing page up/down keys I didn't try those. `fn` + up/down emulates page up/down though and works on my keyboard.